# Как отображать заголовок маркера на Google Maps Android на всех маркерах одновременно?

Tags: android, google-maps, customview, marker

Как отображать заголовок маркера на Google Maps Android на всех маркерах одновременно? Без нажатия на маркер.

Так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

андроид не позволяет одновременно показывать более одного инфовиндов

Comment: да, но есть разные кастомные способы создания, я нашел несколько на англ ресурсе, к примеру: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984118/show-info-window-on-every-marker-at-a-time 
и 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729264/show-dynamically-to-infowindow-googlemap-v2

но у меня так не получается, думал, может тут у кого было такое задание и он нашел решение.

Comment: в первой строке ответа сказано что это невозможно. но также там есть пример создания кастомного маркета (значек маркета + инфовиндов). можно попробовать создать кастомный леяут и использовать IconGenerator для получения иконки маркера. создание таким способом маркера ресурсозатратное. сколько у вас маркеров на карте?

Comment: вот пример того что вам нужно. думаю далее будет не сложно его изменить под свой вид маркера http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/

Comment: да, кажется, это то, что мне нужно, сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо!